# How to upload same file name with auto increment in PHP?

Tags: php, file-upload, server

I got a task where I need to upload the same file name with numbers. For example if I upload file1 with the title "cv.pdf" then second file should be named as "cv.pdf(1)",the next one should be "cv.pdf(2)" and so on.

I have tried many ways but still not working out. Can some please help me out to meet the desired objective. This is my

> upload.php

```
<?php 
$json = array();
if(!empty($_FILES['upl_file'])){ 
    $dir = "./uploads/"; 
    $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'pdf', 'doc', 'docx'); 
    $fileName = basename($_FILES['upl_file']['name']); 
    $filePath = $dir.$fileName; 

$actual_name = pathinfo($filePath,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo($filePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$i = 1;
while(file_exists("./uploads/".$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
} 
    if(in_array($extension, $allowTypes)){ 
        // Upload file to the server 
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl_file']['tmp_name'], $filePath)){ 
            $json = 'success'; 
        } else {
            $json = 'failed';
        }
    } 
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: `$name` seems to hold the new name, where are you using it later on? You're using `$filePath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) function is your savior here.

Istead of:

```
$i = 1;
while(file_exists("./uploads/".$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}
```

You should use:

```
$count = count(glob("./uploads/".$actual_name."*.".$extension)); 
  //Check the * after the name

//EDIT: Before add the count, check if its not zero(0)

$actual_name = "{$name}".( $count > 0 ? "({$count})" : "").".{$extension}";
```

And last, but not least, you should change the final name of the file:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl_file']['tmp_name'], $filePath)) 
  //filePath has the old name

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upl_file']['tmp_name'], $dir.$actual_name))
  //newPath with count in the name
```

Comment: You assume the file names are a series of contiguous numbers...